# Is there a way to bypass windows directory cache?

Tags: c++, windows, caching, smb

According to [this post](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686200(v=ws.10).aspx)

Windows caches directory listings taken from samba share. By default it is for 10 seconds. We implemented solution that relies on kind of magic files that are exposed by smb server only for getting attributes directly but hidden from listing. The problem is, when trying to get attributes of such file from windows client machine while listing is cached, system says that file doesn't exist. Is there any way to bypass this directory cache and ask for attributes of such file directly on samba using c++? Changing system settings is not an option for us.

Comment: Try opening the file and using GetFileInformationByHandle.

Comment: ... if the files are changing, you could also try ReadDirectoryChangesW.